# Error saying, "statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function"

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I'm a beginner programmer, so this is going to look messy, but I keep getting the problem that is mentioned in the title. No matter where I try to put `endl`; it keeps giving me the same error. Also when I run the code my total for the second store comes out right but the first store total does not. Any idea on how to fix this? I'm using codeblocks on a windows 7 computer.

```
#include <iostream> //Allows cout/cin
#include <ctime> //Allows time
#include <iomanip> //Allows setprecision

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Include header

    //Input variables
    double widgetStores;
    double numberSoldFirst1;
    double numberSoldFirst2;
    double numberSoldSecond1;
    double numberSoldSecond2;
    double widgetsLeftS1W2;
    double widgetsLeftS2W1;
    double widgetsLeftS2W2;

    //Start Clock
    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;
    begin = clock();

    //Prompt for total number in stores

    cout << "Total number of widgets at each store starting with :";
    cin >> widgetStores;

    double widgetStore1=widgetStores;
    double widgetStore2=widgetStores;
    double widgetsLeftS1W1;


    //Prompt for amount sold during first and second week

    cout << "How many widgets were sold at Store 1 the first week? ";
    cin >> numberSoldFirst1;
    cout << "How many widgets were sold at Store 1 the 2nd week? ";
    cin >> numberSoldSecond1;
    cout << "How many widgets were sold at Store 2 the first week? ";
    cin >> numberSoldFirst2;
    cout << "How many widgets were sold at Store 2 the 2nd week? ";
    cin >> numberSoldSecond2;

    //Calculate Number of widgets
    widgetsLeftS1W1-=(widgetStore1-numberSoldFirst1);
    widgetsLeftS1W2-=(numberSoldFirst1-numberSoldSecond1);
    widgetsLeftS2W1-=(widgetStore2-numberSoldFirst2);
    widgetsLeftS2W2-=(numberSoldFirst2-numberSoldSecond2);

    //Display Values
    cout << "Store 1 has " << widgetsLeftS1W2 << " widgets left after the 2nd week.";
    cout << "Store 2 has " <<widgetsLeftS2W2 << " widgets left after the 2nd week.";

    //Show time elapsed
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "****Elapsed time:" <<time_spent/60 <<        "minutes****";
    return 0;
```

Comment: Can you show the line that causes the error?

Comment: I cannot see any endl in your program. Paste code you are getting error for.

Comment: Anywhere that I put an endl will cause the error, like I need one after each cin and cout but if I put them there it will cause the error.

Comment: *After* each `cin`? As in: `cin >> something >> endl;` ?

Comment: You haven't initialized any of your variables of the form `widgetsLeftS1W1` before you subtract from them with all the `-=` lines.

Comment: My mistake, not after the cin but after the couts and how would I initialize the variable?

Comment: Hmmm, now that I look again it seems that you should just change all the `-=` to just `=`. And why not put one of your endl's in so we can see where you're putting it.

Comment: That would probably help, but my teacher required us to use the augmented function for this assignment

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Show us the exact error please and the line from which it is coming. Edit your post and add that information in please.

Comment: "Anywhere that I put an endl will cause the error" - that's not a meaningful description of the problem. So, cut the nonsense and post what *exactly* you are doing with that `endl`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
cout << "Total number of widgets at each store starting with :";
cin >> widgetStores;
cout << endl; //Added this
```

cin doesn't have a << operator, so you need to send it to cout.

Edit: I found the error you're having. I guess that you are trying to put in lines as literally

> endl;

and that doesn't go anywhere...

Comment: That's pointless since the input operation will end with a newline anyway (since you have to hit Enter before the input is accepted).

Comment: The question asks how to get an `endl` working. Not whether it's relevant. Maybe he wants a line of space between each pair of input/output.

Answer (score 0):

The only compile error this program has, is that you're using `widgetsLeftS1W1`, `widgetsLeftS1W2`, `widgetsLeftS2W1` and `widgetsLeftS2W2` before initializing them.

[image]

You probably need `=` instead of `-=`.

When you say

```
widgetsLeftS1W1 -= (widgetStore1-numberSoldFirst1);
```

what you actually mean is

```
widgetsLeftS1W1 = widgetsLeftS1W1 - (widgetStore1-numberSoldFirst1);
```

The computer doesn't know the value of **`widgetsLeftS1W1`**, so it gives you the error.

---

Conclusion: use

```
widgetsLeftS1W1 = (widgetStore1 - numberSoldFirst1);
```

Comment: That is not a compile error, in fact a diagnostic isn't even required. It is undefined behavior, but the best you'll get out of the vast majority of compilers is a warning.

Comment: @jerry it is definitely a compile error. See the screenshot

Comment: While I should have been precise and said that the standard doesn't **require** this to be treated as an error, I stand by my assertion that most compilers will only emit a warning (if anything) by default. [GCC happily compiles it](http://ideone.com/MW4pdj), for instance. You seem to be using Visual Studio, even there [C4700 is only a warning by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axhfhh6x.aspx). I'm guessing you've turned on a "treat warnings as errors" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the values of

```
widgetsLeftS1W1
widgetsLeftS1W2
widgetsLeftS2W1
widgetsLeftS2W2
```

with zero while declaring them at the top.